# How to compute the following formula

Tags: math

Given,

```
1*2^1 + 2*2^2 + 3*2^3 + 4*2^4 + ... d * 2^d

= sum(r * 2^r, r from 1 to d)
```

How can we infer to the following solution?

```
= 2 (d-1) * 2^d + 2
```

Thank you

Comment: Try asking that here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you asking for a proof that the solution is correct or a generic way how to convert a series to a closed form?

Comment: @martineno, I am asking the proof that the solution is correct. -- thank you

Answer (score 2):

By [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) on *d*:

**Base Case**

```
d = 1
sum(r * 2^r, r from 1 to 1) = 1 * 2^1 = 1 * 2 = 2
2 * (1 - 1) * 2^1 + 2 = 2 * 0 * 2 + 2 = 0 + 2 = 2
```

**Inductive Case**

We assume that the inductive hypothesis is true for *d* thus:

```
sum(r * 2^r, r from 1 to d + 1) =
sum(r * 2^r, r from 1 to d) + [(d + 1) * 2^(d + 1)] =
2 * (d-1) * 2^d + 2 + [(d + 1) * 2^(d + 1)] =
(d - 1) * 2^(d + 1) + 2 + d * 2^(d + 1) + 2^(d + 1) =
d * 2^(d + 1) - 2^(d + 1) + 2 + d * 2^(d + 1) + 2^(d + 1) =
d * 2^(d + 1) + 2 + d * 2^(d + 1) =
2 * d * 2^(d + 1) + 2 (result 1)
```

*and* now evaluate your formula for `d + 1`

```
2 (d-1) * 2^d + 2 = (substituting d + 1 for d)
2 * (d + 1 - 1) * 2^(d + 1) + 2 =
2 * d * 2^(d + 1) + 2 (result 2)
```

*thus*

```
2 * d * 2^(d + 1) + 2 (result 1) = 2 * d * 2^(d + 1) + 2 (result 2)
```

*QED*

Comment: thank you for your detail induction. However, my original question was asking how to get the solution rather than given the solution and prove the solution is correct. -- thx

Comment: @q0987 no problem, but when I asked you in the original question whether you wanted a way how to get to the solution or to prove that the solution was correction you said "@martineno, I am asking the proof that the solution is correct." So I am confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can show this by proof by induction:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_induction